# Excel-VBA update userform listbox based on existing list

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a useform with multicolumn listbox which lists items and its quantity. The intent is to be able to dynamically update the quantity by adding or deducting from a textbox input. Below is my current code roughly to realize this. So far it is not working with invalid qualifier error for selected(i). would appreciate any guidance on this

```
    Private Sub CB_AddOrder_Click()

   Dim j, k, qty As Integer
   Dim i As Variant

   qty = TB_Qty.Value

   If qty = 0 Then
   Exit Sub
   End If

   j = LB_Order.ListCount - 1

   Debug.Print j

   If j < 0 Then
   j = 0
   End If

   'Iterate to check if selected menu already existed in ordered list

   For i = 0 To LB_Menu.ListCount - 1
   If LB_Menu.Selected(i) = True Then
   Debug.Print Selected(i)

   For k = 0 To j
   If LB_Menu.Selected(i).List(i, 0) = LB_Order.List(k, 0) Then
   LB_Order.List(k, 3) = LB_Order.List(k, 3).Value + qty
   Exit Sub
   End If
   Next k
        
   With LB_Order
   .ColumnCount = 5
   .ColumnWidths = "120;60;60;60;60"
   .AddItem
   .List(j, 0) = LB_Menu.List(i, 0)
   .List(j, 1) = LB_Menu.List(i, 1)
   .List(j, 2) = LB_Menu.List(i, 2)
   .List(j, 3) = qty
   .List(j, 4) = Format(qty * LB_Menu.List(i, 2), "0.00")
    End With
    End If

    Next i

    End sub
```

Comment: The qualifier error is because you can't add `.List(i, 0)` as a qualifier to `Selected(i)`. You'll have to grab the selected index and store the `.List(i, 0)` in a variable, then use that to compare to `LB_Order.List(k, 0)` if your `If` statement.

Comment: @PeterT thank you for the feedback n apologies for the late reply. i've introduced a new variable to perform the comparison but now having an object required error. May you show me how you would have written it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion you're having relates from the difference in which listbox item(s) are selected and the value of those selected item(s). So when you check for `Selected`:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To LB_Menu.ListCount - 1
    If LB_Menu.Selected(i) Then
        Debug.Print "Menu selected (" & i & ") = " & LB_Menu.List(i, 0)
    End If
Next i
```

Once you determine which ***index*** (`i` in this case) is selected, you refer to the value by using the index into the `List`.

The `Object Required` error you received is because your statement

```
LB_Order.List(k, 3) = LB_Order.List(k, 3).Value + qty
```

is using `.Value` for the list item. This item is a value, not an object.

Here is your sub rewritten as an example. Notice that I'm using single-character variables as loop indexes (which is good), but not as a meaningful value. I renamed other variables in (a hopefully) meaningful way to make your code a little more self-documenting.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CB_AddOrder_Click()
    Dim additionalQty As Long
    additionalQty = TB_Qty.Value

    If additionalQty = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim countOfOrderItems As Long
    countOfOrderItems = LB_Order.ListCount - 1
    If countOfOrderItems < 0 Then
        countOfOrderItems = 0
    End If

    'Iterate to check if selected menu already existed in ordered list
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To LB_Menu.ListCount - 1
        If LB_Menu.Selected(i) Then
            Debug.Print "Menu selected (" & i & ") = " & LB_Menu.List(i, 0)
            
            '--- find the matching item and increase the quantity
            Dim k As Long
            For k = 0 To countOfOrderItems
                If LB_Menu.List(i) = LB_Order.List(k, 0) Then
                    LB_Order.List(k, 3) = LB_Order.List(k, 3) + additionalQty
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next k
        
            '--- append the new item from the Menu to the Order
            With LB_Order
                .ColumnCount = 5
                .ColumnWidths = "120;60;60;60;60"
                .AddItem
                .List(countOfOrderItems, 0) = LB_Menu.List(i, 0)
                .List(countOfOrderItems, 1) = LB_Menu.List(i, 1)
                .List(countOfOrderItems, 2) = LB_Menu.List(i, 2)
                .List(countOfOrderItems, 3) = additionalQty
                .List(countOfOrderItems, 4) = Format(additionalQty * LB_Menu.List(i, 2), "0.00")
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

By the way, make sure all of the columns in your listboxes are initialized with values if you will add/subtract number values. If they are just `Null`, you'll get a `Could not set the List property` error.